# How to retry connect multiple times when doing http request in node.js if the server is not responding?

Tags: node.js

If a server is not responding, how can I retry the connect?
I get the error `ECONNREFUSED`, but I want to retry the connection at least 5 times.

Here is my code:

```
var body = JSON.stringify(saveObj);
var request = http.request({
    host: BASE_URL,
    port: PORT,
    path: LINK_SAVE,
    url : 'https://coherent-bay-777.appspot.com/_ah/api/timesOfIndia/v1/addChannel',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body)
    }
}, function(res) {
    var resp = '';
    res.on('data', function(data) {
        resp += data;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        resp = JSON.parse(resp);
        if(resp.id) {
        winston.info(resp.id);
            saveObj.update({$set : { id : resp.id }},
                function(err) {
                    if(err) {
                        winston.error(err);
                    } else {
                        cb();
                    }
                });
        } else {
            cb();
        }

    });
    res.on('error', function(err) {
        winston.error(err);
        //cb();
    });
    winston.info('Request Ended');
});

if(body == '{}') {
    cb();
    return;
}

request.on('socket', function (socket) {

    socket.setTimeout(15000);  
    socket.on('timeout', function() {
        console.log("Timeout, aborting request")
        request.abort();
    });
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
      error callback will receive a "socket hang up" on timeout
});


request.write(body);
request.end();
```

Comment: You can use `retry` function from `async` library

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin Is there any way I can do it with standard `http` module ?

Comment: You can wrap it into a function and call it in the loop until it's not successful

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin Yeah , it will work .